# GTMetrix Grey Items on Report

Tags: optimization, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, gtmetrix

I am having an [image]issue understanding my report. There are items that show up and a duplicate shows up with no file size but a certain amount of time for receiving.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this is that you are using `rel="preload"` and then not using the resource within a few seconds.

With the limited information provided I can only guess that you might be preloading the resource at say `https://www.` but your page is on `https://`. It could also be similar naming issues, `@includes` etc. You will have to investigate yourself.

The easiest way to do this is to load the site in your browser and check the console for warnings similar to the following:-

> The resource **your font URL** was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window’s load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Comment: Yeah, but they are coming from the Recaptcha gstatic.com and fonts.gstatic.com. I checked and don't have any preloads. The file in the image is from a Recaptcha file. Plus I am using wp rocket preload which removes https://www.

Comment: if you want to share the URL for your site I can look into it for you, from the info provided that was my best guess but it will be something closely related to preloading / unused resources.

Comment: The website is [link](https://nuestravision.tv) @graham